# Angular2 with Firebase (push) messaging, how to get token

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using an Angular2 web app (PWA with manifest and NGSW service-worker) I can not get Firebase messaging working. On requesting a token (firebase.messaging().getToken()) I get:

> messaging/token-subscribe-failed Request is missing required
>   authentication credential

If I use @angular/service-worker SwPush I can get a PushSubscription using swPush.requestSubscription(). If I then use the Web Push library for Node.js in a Firebase cloud function I can successfully send push messages using the subscriptions I got back from swPush.requestSubscription().

By the way, in swPush.requestSubscription() I use a generated public VAPID which I also registered in the Firebase console for Firebase to use.

So **NOT working** - Firebase messaging, **working** - swPush with Web Push

Questing-1: Is there any advantage using Firebase messaging (as I can just use the working setup)? I was thinking maybe sending push notifications to topics (I did not yet test this with the working setup).

Question-2: If there are advantages, how to get around this error when trying to get a token, what could be the cause?

The request that fails sends:

```
authorized_entity:  xxxxxxx
endpoint: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/yyyyyyyy
encryption_key: zzzzzzzzzz
encryption_auth: qqqqqqqqqq
```

Which gets back the 401

But the enpoint, key and auth are exactly what I get back from the working swPush.requestSubscription(), so Firebase manages to send correct (I guess) subscription details. What is happening at the backend then? Don't know what the authorized_entity is or does, could not find any reference to it in the docs. Maybe there is a mismatch somehow.

Code (mainly the example code from the Firebase docs):

```
  pushSubscribeFB() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(swreg => {
      console.log('swreg with getregistration: ', swreg)
      if(swreg){
        firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(swreg)
        firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(function() {
          console.log('Notification permission granted.');
          firebase.messaging().getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
            if (currentToken) {
              console.log('token: ', currentToken)
              // sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
              // updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
            } else {
              // Show permission request.
              console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
              // Show permission UI.
              // updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
              // setTokenSentToServer(false);
            }
          }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
            // showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
            // setTokenSentToServer(false);
          });
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
        });
      }
    }).catch(err => console.log('could not get SW: ', err))
  }
```